# Question about Dirac comb

Tags: real-analysis, laplace-transform

I got the following question from a test:

[image]

I think something is wrong with the question. Otherwise, i will appreciate a way of solving it.

Comment: Looks like it has a tent function centered about $t=na$, so, if the slope of the tent is properly set the area under each $\wedge$ should be one. But, perhaps there is more you are to show? It should be assumed that $m$ is large enough so the teeth of the comb do not overlap I guess.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook That tent has a basement, holes in the walls, and zero square feet.

Comment: @Y.ofir Change the first expression of $G_{m,a}$ into $(t-na+1/m)m^2$ and the second into $(-t+na+1/m)m^2$.

Comment: @orole Thanks! you're right, that $a$ is out of place there. If we set $t = na-1/m$ or $t = na+1/m$ then in the respective cases the formulas work out to zero as we'd expect. Apparently, the shift was wrong in the statement, but, the slope of $m^2$ was actually ok.